# I am getting strange error on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Please any one help me.
This is the error: Error:No such property: nexusUsername for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

stacktrace

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:compileDebugJava]
Information:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Information:* What went wrong:
Information:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Information:> A problem occurred configuring project':libraries:HoloColorPicker-    master'.
Information:   > No such property: nexusUsername for class:        org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer
       Information:* Try:
          Information:Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info                       or --debug option to get more log output.
Information:0 errors
```

settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
include ':libraries:HoloColorPicker-master'
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile project(':libraries:HoloColorPicker-master')
}
```

Holopicker build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

def isReleaseBuild() {
    return version.contains("SNAPSHOT") == false
}

allprojects {
    version = VERSION_NAME
    group = GROUP

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}

apply from: 'maven_push.gradle'
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `HoloColorPicker` library has gradle tasks for uploading to the Maven repository that require some properties to be set for the gradle environment (usually in `gradle.properties`).

The easiest solution would be to remove the line from `build.gradle`:

```
apply from: 'maven_push.gradle'
```

Comment: Which part needs to be moved to maven_push.gradle? Could you please specify? Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I have not try the solution given by myanimal, but i have try out another thing which works with all the project which have similar issue during importing it. myanimal's solution is related to only one project, and for every project you should have to follow same thing.

But with my solution you might have to do it only once for all future projects.

For my solution do like below:

**- create a file ~/.gradle/gradle.properties with the following contents:**

> ```
> nexusUsername=
> nexusPassword=
> ```

Hope this will help you more for all projects.

Comment: This is by far the best answer. This answer should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This answer works as mentionned on the github https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/issues/188

Comment: Thanks. simple and fast